# Calculate differences between consecutive dates in Hive arrays

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

I am using Hive, and need to calculate the difference (in days) between consecutive dates stored in an array contained in each row of a table, in order to get the gaps between recorded times. Each row is for one customer, and contains their transaction dates. For example (last column is the desired output):

```
customer_id | dates                                                |output 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
0001        | ["2016-09-01","2017-01-01","2017-02-05","2017-11-01"]|[122,35,269]
```

Aim is to iterate through all rows in the table producing this new column. Customers will have different numbers of transactions, so I will need to loop through the list of dates.

Comment: If your question is not about Mysql, please don't tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the input table is `array_test` and output table is `output_table`. Also, the array_test contains columns `customer_id string` and `dates Array<string>`
The data i inserted in input table is:

```
insert into array_test select "0001",ARRAY("2016-09-01","2017-01-01","2017-02-05","2017-11-01")
insert into array_test select "0001",ARRAY("2016-09-01","2017-01-01","2017-02-05","2017-11-02")
```

The output table create statement i used is:

```
CREATE TABLE output_table(customer_id string,dates array<string>,output array<int>);
```

Then use the below query to select from input table and insert into output table:

```
insert into output_table select customer_id,dates, ARRAY(datediff(to_date(dates[1]), to_date(dates[0])),datediff(to_date(dates[2]), to_date(dates[1])),datediff(to_date(dates[3]), to_date(dates[2]))) from array_test;
```

Below is the output:

```
hive> select output from output_table;
OK
[122,35,269]
[122,35,269]
[122,35,270]
[122,35,270]
Time taken: 0.071 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Comment: The main problem I have is that each customer will have a different number of transactions, so I can't hard-code array indexes. This needs a loop or lambda-type operation, which I am not able to implement.

Comment: if that is the case, always there is a option to implement a UDF in hive and do all the operations. If you are ok to use udf, then implemnt the logic there in java code.